# Using Software Update Server

Tags: macos, network, software-update, osx-server, server.app

I'm using Mavericks Server to serve Apple Software Updates to my various Macs. Apparently, I have to point the client at the server, specifying my URL "e.g. http://su.domain_name.com:8088/index.sucatalog".

How do I find out this info for my setup? I haven't defined a URL for my server on the local network; 8088 is I gather the default port for the Software Update Server; but I don't know where or what the file is called either.

Answer (score 4):

#### Summary:

The simple way to configure a client to point to your Software Update server is using the following Terminal command on your client:

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.SoftwareUpdate CatalogURL http://su.domain_name.com:8088/index.sucatalog
```

Replace `su.domain_name.com` with your server's fully qualified domain name as specified in Server.app. You can find your FQDM by going to **Server.app** → **[server name]** → **Access: Host Name**:

[image]

You can change your FQDM by clicking the **Edit…** button on the right.

---

#### More detail:

1. Set a host name by going to **Server.app** → **[server name]** → **Access: Host Name** → **Edit…**. If you wish to access your server over the internet without VPN, choose Domain Name. Otherwise, choose one of the Local Network options.

   [image]
2. Switch on the Software Update service.

   [image]
3. Once the service has started, you can find the FQDM in the Access section.

   [image]
4. Using this FQDM, you can find your CatalogURL by substituting this into the following URL:

   ```
   http://[FQDM]:8088/index.sucatalog
   ```

   <sup>For example, if my FQDM is reported under the Access section as `server.example.private`, my Software Update catalog would be located at `http://server.example.private:8088/index.sucatalog`.</sup>
5. On your clients, you can configure them by running the following Terminal command:

   ```
   sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.SoftwareUpdate CatalogURL [your-catalogURL]
   ```

   Replace `[your-catalogURL]` with the URL that you got from step 4.

You can revert your settings by running the following Terminal command:

```
sudo defaults delete /Library/Preferences/com.apple.SoftwareUpdate CatalogURL
```

Alternatively, you can use Profile Manger to provide OTA configuration using the Custom Settings section of your configuration profile.

Comment: So the domain for the URL is just my host name.
And the rest of it is always "8088/index.sucatalog"...?

Comment: @Ben Yes, unless you specifically change it or have awkward settings in your Web service or Profile Manager that is accidentally breaking it… :)

Comment: BOOM! That's an awesome and comprehensive answer.